# how to produce bigrams without stop words

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

i wrote this function for generating bigrams from string using nltk.bigrams and ignoring stop words and letters but the stop words and letters still appear in the output. please help me to correct the funtion.

```
       def bigramReturner (tweetString, stopWords):
           bigramFeatureVector = []
           tweetStringG = tweetString.lower()
           tweetStringG = tweetString.split()
           for i in tweetStringG:
               i =replaceTwoOrMore(i)
               i =i.strip('\'"?,.')
               val = re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", i)
               if(i in stopWords  is None):
                   continue
               else:
                  for i in nltk.bigrams(tweetStringG):
                        bigramFeatureVector.append(' '.join(i))
           return bigramFeatureVector
```

Comment: `if(i in stopWords  is None)` --> usually done as `if i not in stopWords` . Also, to me it looks like you are explicitly matching stop words, rather than excluding them? (if not in stopwords): Y, (else:) append to bigramFeatureVector. Or am I misreading this?

Comment: I don't think (i in stopWords  is None) is a reasonable statement. False != None. Also you check the wrong case, even if this would not be true. You want to continue if it is in stopWords, not if it is not.

Comment: i have similar function that converting tweet to a set of tokens   and it is working

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `is None` check as currently you're comparing `True` or `False` with `None`

```
   def bigramReturner (tweetString, stopWords):
       bigramFeatureVector = []
       tweetStringG = tweetString.lower()
       tweetStringG = tweetString.split()
       for i in tweetStringG:
           i =replaceTwoOrMore(i)
           i =i.strip('\'"?,.')
           val = re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", i)
           if(i in stopWords):
               continue
           else:
              for i in nltk.bigrams(tweetStringG):
                    bigramFeatureVector.append(' '.join(i))
       return bigramFeatureVector
```

Comment: Still not working, i think the problem in nltk.bigrams